# teamcity ant build

Tags: ant, build, teamcity

So i have 4 project depend on each other with 4 different configuration in team city. when i run 1 they all run. but , each one of them is doing check out when starting his run , so it is possible that some files were committed during build and than it is not the same revision. 
i want to be able to checkout them all at the beginning so the build will be always the same revision.

does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If they are all pulling from the same repository you can create a snapshot dependancy from the dependent build to the build they are dependent on. What this means is that they will use the same sources as the build that they are depending on.

[Snapshot Dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency)

Answer (score 0):

You could group the projects logically in version control and add a parent script to build them in order. You then have one TC checkout/build that does all 4.

We use maven multi-module builds in Hudson for the same purpose.